# What does that mean if there is no bifurcations in my time series single cell data?

Tags: single-cell, matlab

Sorry,

I have analysed my time series single cell data with Scuba algorithm but that says that there is no bifurcations in my data and outputted a single chain of 4 states with no branching like below figure

[image]

Sorry, I googled but I am not quite sure what this means

Any suggestion please?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most obvious interpretation is that the four cell lines are related in a linear pathway rather than a branching one.